# headless AJDT build fails when upgrading java from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: eclipse, ajdt

strong texti have a very simple eclipse 3.8-based rcp application with an .aj file. i also have AJDT 2.2.1 installed, and have the following four entries in my build.properties:

```
javacSource=1.6
javacTarget=1.6

compilerAdapter=org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ant.AJDT_AjcCompilerAdapter
sourceFileExtensions=*.java, *.aj
```

i am using a headless build approach via Ant, and it has been working like a charm, AJDT and all, while using java 1.6. but once i upgraded from java 1.6 to 1.7, and changed the two aforementioned build.properties entries' -- javacSource and javacTarget -- values from 1.6 to 1.7, i got a boat-load of build errors, all with the following suffix:

```
... are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

setting build.properties' **javacSource** back to 1.6, while leaving **javacTarget** at 1.7 works. or if i were to comment out the two AJDT-specific entries from my build.properties, while leaving **javacSource** and **javacTarget** values at 1.7. the build completes just fine as well. so my guess is that AJDT compiler is somehow the culprit. the question is why and what can be done to resolve it.

thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one of two things:

1. Your AJDT installed does not have an AspectJ in it that is compatible with Java 1.7.  What AspectJ version are you building with?  Note that this aspectj version may be different from the one in your target platform.
2. You are not correctly specifying the Java source/target version in a way that AspectJ can recognize.  How are you specifying the Java source/target version?

Comment: thanks for responding, Andrew.

1. i have ajdt 2.2.1 installed, which is the very latest version. the actual version of the org.aspectj weaver, runtime, and ajde plugins is 1.7.2. i also drilled down into org.aspectj.runtime plugin to the aspectjrt.jar, and found the following entry in its MANIFEST.MF: "Specification-Version: 1.7". don't know if that is of any help. please let me know if there are other locations to verify the version.

2. i have the following two entries in my build.properties:
javacSource=1.7
javacTarget=1.7
should there be some additional entries? perhaps in ant.properties?

Comment: updated my question text with more info to be more detailed. i wonder if aspectj somehow reverts back to its default source value of 1.4, thereby triggering the error. as a result, i attempted to rectify the problem by adding "compilerArg=-1.7" entry to build.properties, but without success.

Comment: Thanks for the description.  I was able to track down the problem and raised a bug report here:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395960

Comment: The AJC task was missing a flag for 1.7.  I added it and it now works for me.  Fix will be available in next dev build.  Use this update site to get it: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/42/dev/update/